# Having issues showing/hiding div on "onclick" event in select in chrome

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a form where user can select "billing address is same as shipping address" as yes or no on select. I am trying to show/hide a div on select with jquery Show () hide(). Here's the code i am using:

```
<select name="use_shipping_as_billing" >
<option value="Yes" selected="selected"  onclick="$('#billing_form').hide();" >Yes</option>
 <option value="No" onclick="$('#billing_form').show();"  >No</option>
</select>
```

Its working fine in FF but div is not showing/hiding in Chrome. I searched a lot and tried many other options including onchange() but nothing seems to work. Any inputs would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: I'd leverage the power of jQuery to eliminate that `inline` JavaScript.  BTW, you don't `click` on items in a select list. And the event should be inside the `<select>`, not the `<option>`.

Comment: The same script works fine with radio buttons on chrome also but doesnt work with select.

Comment: Again, that's because, the event is supposed to be tied to the `select` and not the `option`.  How is anyone supposed to `click` on the `option`?  They don't... they can only release their button.  And the `option` never changes... each `option` item is always the same... the `select` is what changes.

Comment: I agree with Sparky, faced a similar situation before.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="use_shipping_as_billing" >
 <option value="Yes" selected="selected" >Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select[name=use_shipping_as_billing]').change(function(){
            if(this.value === "Yes")
               $('#billing_form').hide();
            else
               $('#billing_form').show();
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @roasted, Thanks for quick help. It worked! But any idea why chrome doesn't show() hide() on select.

Comment: Because your code was not valid: setting onclick handler on option element.  (same for IE i think)